# Redirect form post after successful form submission to an external url page in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user registration form in my laravel page, and I want it to redirect users to another Wordpress url for example my form is in url1.com and I wish that after form submission it takes routes the users to another url url2.com

I have tried passing url to the HTTP Controller that I created

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Report;

class ReportsController extends Controller
{
    //



    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([

                    'name'=>'required',
                    'phone'=>'required',
                    'email'=>'required',
                    'address'=>'required',
                    'state'=>'required',
                    'message'=>'required',
                ]);

        // Create Courier
         $reports = new Report;

         $reports->name = $request->input('name');
         $reports->phone = $request->input('phone');
         $reports->email = $request->input('email');
         $reports->address = $request->input('address');
         $reports->state = $request->input('state');
         $reports->message = $request->input('message');

         $reports->save();


        return redirect("http://url2.com");
    }
}
```

I expected it to redirect to the passed url, but it wouldn't

Comment: Looks like you missed the closing quote: `return redirect("http://url2.com");`

Comment: That redirect statement should work perfectly fine. What is happening when you say it does not redirect? Does it show any errors? Does it stay on the same page as the form when you submit it? Are you sure the validation passes, since `$request->validate()` will redirect back automatically to your form URL if the validation conditions are not met, hence the return statment will never get executed. Try commenting out everything in your `store()` method and keep only the redirect line `return redirect("http://url2.com");`. Does it work that way?

Comment: Also is this a synchronous request or an AJAX request?

Comment: Thank you, It's now working, I cleared the cache and blade views from Artisan, Also I managed to add some Validations on the form elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed a second semicolon on your redirect call, fix it and try again

Comment: I think you meant second quote.